# Joomla Component pagination doesn't work

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I'm building a Joomla component and trying to create a pagination for my list but doesn't show anything
this is a code for default.php

```
<tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
```

and my view.html

```
protected $patients;
protected $pagination;
public $filterForm;
public $activeFilters;
 public function display($tpl = null)
{

    $this->patients = $this->get('Items');
    $this->pagination   = $this->get('Pagination');
    $this->filterForm    = $this->get('FilterForm');
    $this->activeFilters = $this->get('ActiveFilters');
    labHelper::addSubmenu('patients');
    $this->addToolBar();
    $this->sidebar = JHtmlSidebar::render();

    return parent::display($tpl);
}
```

is there somthing wrong !?